# org.apache.jena.atlas.web.ContentType.getContentTypeStr()Ljava/lang/String NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, maven, sparql, rdf, jena

I'm using JENA API for connecting to my JENA FUSEKI Server. This is my code: (I copied it from documentation)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String connectionString =          "http://localhost:8080/fuseki";
    RDFConnection conn =         RDFConnectionFactory.connect(connectionString);
                    conn.load("C:\\Users\\Rita\\Desktop\\parenthood.owl") ;
            QueryExecution qExec = conn.query("SELECT         DISTINCT ?s { ?s ?p ?o }") ;
            ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect() ;
            while(rs.hasNext()) {
                QuerySolution qs = rs.next() ;
                Resource subject = qs.getResource("s") ;
                System.out.println("Subject: "+subject) ;
            }
            qExec.close() ;
            conn.close() ;

        }
```

When i try to run it, i have this exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jena.atlas.web.ContentType.getContentTypeStr()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.doPutPost(RDFConnectionRemote.java:423)
at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.upload(RDFConnectionRemote.java:407)
at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.load(RDFConnectionRemote.java:356)
at Connection_test.main(Connection_test.java:14)
```

So I saw the RDFCOnnectionremote.java code, and it imports "org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;" and not "org.apache.jena.atlas.web.ContentType", as I would expect. I tried also to add "org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient" dependency to pom.xml, but it doesn't work.I'm using EClipse Ide. Please help me!
Rita

Comment: check your Maven dependencies. Most likely, you have different versions of the Jena artifacts in your classpath. `mvn dependency:tree` will show you

Comment: Thank you very much! I checked and I have different versions of Jena artifacts.I tried to delete .m2 directory, and  I ran  `mvn -U clean install ` but it downloads different version of artifacts again. Have you some suggestions to fix it? is there some methods to force updates?

Comment: How do you run your programme? Check that agrees with the project setup: `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @Ritulla in the dependency tree, you can see from where the different versions come from. This is where you have to start. We don't know you POM file at all.

Comment: I really thanks both of you! I found the issue and solve it. :)